# phalcon php built-in server Failed opening required .htrouter

Tags: php, phalcon, php-builtin-server

Trying to run phalcon 2.0.7 app using built-in http server in php 5.6 and included .htrouter to make URI rewrite working. Everything seems find until I use `die()` in controller. For the first time it works as expected but when refreshed it throws PHP fatal error:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '.htrouter.php' (include_path='.:') in Unknown on line 0
```

Is there a way to fix that or should I start configuring other http server?

Comment: I tested with this [Main Doc](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/built-in.html) & it's works perfectly. does your `.htrouter.php`  have correct code?

Comment: Didn't change anything, project created by phalcon dev-tools

Comment: which type of proeject did you create & use? (micro,simple,multi)

Comment: Whatever the default is, I guess it's simple

Comment: Ok, does your `.htrouter.php` has `.php` extension ? & the content of it is the same as the Main doc?

Comment: yes and yes. you see, everything is fine until I use die() somewhere in controller, then this occurs. Did you try that?

Comment: yes, i test it & no problem with `die()` function. where you locate `.htrouter.php` ? did you launch your webserver exactly like : `php -S localhost:8000 -t public .htrouter.php` ?

Comment: Sorry, late answer but yes, everything as you said. first request prints die message and then for the next requests it fails with fatal errors

Comment: hmm, i don't know other solution. try ask in phalconphp forum, may be you can find your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the .htrouter in my public dir so this helped a lot:

```
php -S localhost:8000 -t public public/.htrouter.php :)
```